# Jackson Mixin and java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, mixins

I have a json something like this

```
 {
  meta: {
    key: value
    key value....
  }
    data:[{
   key: value ....
    }]
 }
```

I am trying to use Mixin with Jackson

```
   class ResponseMixin
     MetaMixin meta;
     ResponseMixin data;
```

I do have a model for all these 3 mixiins and i have a module to map both

```
   class Response
     Meta meta;
     Response data;
```

when i try to read the json, its not reading the whole json,   I feel is the reason for this is because its trying to read something like this

```
       {responseMixin {meta: {...} data: [{..}]}}
```

but the main string i am getting is without responseMixin

Anyone tell me how to avoid this

Comment: Which framework? How are you configuring Jackson? In general your best bet is to first make sure mix-in works with stand-alone Jackson; then figure out if/why framework is not using mix-in configuration correctly.

Comment: i do confirm that my Jackson module is called both in constructor and in setupModule method.

Answer (score 0):

sorry,  Its working i was missing the default constructor